# Is there any way to apply slice pipe in html datalist options? (Angular 8)

Tags: angular, slice

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
       formControlName="location" list="codes"
       (change)="selectedLocation($event.target.value)" 
       placeholder="Location" />

<datalist id="codes">
       <option *ngFor="let city of cityLists | slice:0:3" 
               [value]="city.cityName"></option>
</datalist>
```

i want to show only 5 city lists when user clicks on input tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you do `slice` in `selectedLocation()`

This is not a optimal solution (but if you want to do in html template)

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let city of cityLists; let i = index">
    <option *ngIf="i < 3" [value]="city.cityName">{{ city.cityName }}</option>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. but answer is not worthy

Comment: i want to show only 3 city when user focus on input tag, but with your answer when user type any cityName in the input tag it not only filter the city from the 3 cities

Comment: i want to filter the cityName from all the present cities